# Connect .sdf file at PDA using Win Form App

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have 2 projects

1. windows smart device project which is using .sdf database at PDA.
2. Windows form application .

In windows form application i want to read data from .sdf file located at PDA. I tried many connection string but still could not get connected to .sdf at PDA .**My win form app is running on LapTop.**. I can view .sdf file at PDA using Windows Mobile device center.
The path where .sdf file at PDA is

```
\\\Program Files\ProjectName\db.sdf
```

---

```
this.con = new SqlCeConnection();
this.con.ConnectionString =" Data Source=\\Program Files\ProjectName\db.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to copy the device database file to your desktop in order to access from your Winforms app, you can use http://rapi.codeplex.com to do this.

Answer (score 0):

@ErikEj your answer is good so +1 also it  has little help on how to use it
, I want to do things in simple way.
Here is the link for people who want to do things in simple fashion

http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2009/11/copy-file-from-desktoppc-to-pda-or.html#.UgCeluX6SIU